# MySQL - Set a column name to the ID on creation?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to implement a custom sort field for a list of records.  When I create a new record, by default I would like this field to match the ID number of that record.  Is there any way to achieve this without having to perform two queries?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a strange plan... can you give an example?

Comment: yeah, why dont you sort by ID instead?

Comment: I only want it set to the ID by default.  Once the user has created it, they can reorder the record by dragging it up or down in a HTML table which updates the record via an AJAX call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the `next` auto-increment id by using

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM tablename LIKE Auto_increment
/*or*/
SELECT `auto_increment` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` WHERE table_name = 'tablename'
```

This will give you the **next** auto_increment value.

Then make a before insert trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER bi_table1_each BEFORE INSERT ON table1 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE next_id integer;
  SELECT `auto-increment` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` INTO Next_id 
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table1' LIMIT 1;     
  SET new.sortcolumn = next_id;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

**Links**
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-table-status.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tables-table.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you can leave this field equal to NULL by default and then in your query do this:

```
ORDER BY ifnull(sort_field, id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Set it to null or something like that by default and make your query [sort by id if the sort field is null](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull). PseudoSQL:

```
SELECT blah, IFNULL(t.sort, t.id) AS sortval
FROM t
ORDER BY sortval
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `MAX(ID)` expression to be sure that your next `INSERT` will be the greater id + 1 :

```
INSERT INTO table_name (..., sort_field) VALUES (..., MAX(id)+1)
```

Hope this helps, bye!

Comment: Wrong. MAX(id)+1 is not always equal to auto-incremented id.